# What's the difference between memmove and bcopy?

Tags: c, memmove

I understand the difference between `memcpy` and `memmove`: `memmove` handles the overlapping of `src` and `dst`. I checked the [man page for `bcopy`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bcopy.3.html) and it seems to also handle overlapping. So I'm wondering if there is any difference between `memmove` and `bcopy`?

Comment: This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001): use memcpy(3) or memmove(3) in new programs.

Comment: I note that `memove` and `memcpy` are part of the C standard library, but `bcopy` is specific to POSIX so it won't be available on non-POSIX platforms like Windows.

Comment: You will still find `bcopy`, `bzero`, etc.. in old code. (especially networking code for some reason). Those have gone the way of the Dodo and the `mem...()` functions should be used now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bcopy` and `memmove` do exactly the same thing.  However, they take arguments in a different order: `bcopy(src, dest, n)` vs `memmove(dest, src, n)`.  So they can't be two names for the same function.

Historically, `bcopy` is the older of the two; it was present in 3BSD if memory serves.  `memmove` was invented by the C committee in 1988 or so.

New code should use `memmove`, as it is required by the C standard and therefore more portable than `bcopy`.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference normally comes from their origin.  `bcopy` comes from Berkeley Source Distribution (BSD) systems, while `memcpy` and their family come mainly from AT&T's System V.  And finally, by complying with legacy code, all those functions were included in the standards.

There's a good explanation about the use of `memset` vs `bzero` in Richard Steven's book [*"UNIX network programming"*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) that somewhat explains about the use of either one.

Today implementations just resolve to calling the same internal implementation but providing both interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Functionally they are equivalent. The difference is in portability. `memmove` is part of the C standard while `bcopy` is part of POSIX, and is therefore less portable.

`bcopy` is deprecated. The man page says:

> This function is deprecated (marked as LEGACY in POSIX.1-2001): use `memcpy(3)` or `memmove(3)` in new programs.  Note that the first two arguments are interchanged for `memcpy(3)` and `memmove(3)`.  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of `bcopy()`.